# mobx computed value not updating(Observe) on UI at the first time but after reload

Tags: flutter, mobx

I'm using **MobX** to manage my global state of the app. The problem is I'm using some computed values om my UI but those values not updating on UI but when i print those values in my mobx modal those computed values are computed correctly.

This is my model.

```
abstract class _User with Store {
  _User(this.name, this.subjects);

  @observable
  String name;

  @observable
  List<Spend> subjects;

  @computed
  int get totalSubjects => this.subjects.length;

  @action
  void addSubject(String name) {
    subjects.add(Spend(name));
    print(totalSubjects);
    // If i print the value this gives me correct length of subjects array, But this not oberving on UI
  }
}
```

Only the computed value is not updating. But when i add the subject that subject reflect correctly.

I'm using `flutter_mobx: ^1.1.0+2` and `sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

adding removing or any types of updates to a List is not observed only asigning does, if you want use a List which an be observed Use `ObservableList`